# how to disable html body on pop-up and close pop-up on document click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

On my bootstrap html page I am using a modal pop-up by fade-in and fade-out(j-Query functions) of a div.

(I tried using a bootstrap modal pop-over,but the error was shown, stating 'popover function is not known'.)

Pop-up contains a registration form.Pop-up works fine,there is no close button within my pop-up,so I want my pop-up to be closed when the user clicks anywhere within the body except pop-up area,also i want to disable the html body when the pop-up is shown.

At present I the pop-up will be closed if a click anywhere within html body(that includes the pop-up area also!!!)

In short,what I need is:
(1) Pop-up shouldn't be closed when clicked within the pop-up area 
(2) When pop-up is shown user shouldn't access any link or text-box in the html-body(I have got no idea how to do this!!)

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group row ">
            <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <label for="firstName ">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control create-form" id="firstname">
            </section>
            <section class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-6">
                <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control create-form" id="LastName">
            </section>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $(document).click(function (e) {
             var t = (e.target)
             if (t != $("#popup_box").get(0) && 
             t != $("#popup_box").find('.create-form')) {
                 unloadPopupBox();
             }
         });

         $('.container').click(function (e) {

             var t = (e.target)
             if (t != $("#popup_box").get(0) && t != $("#new-account").get(0)) {
                 unloadPopupBox();
             }
             if (t != $(".navbar-toggle").get(0)) {
                 e.stopPropagation();
             }
         });

         $('#new-account').click(function (e) {
             loadPopupBox();
         });

         function unloadPopupBox() {    
             $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
             $('.container').css({ 
                 "opacity": "1"
             });
         }

         function loadPopupBox() {   
             $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
             $('.container').css({ 
                 "opacity": "0.5",
                 "z-index": "999"
             });
         }
     });
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you.

```
 $("#popup_box").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;        
    });
```

Comment: @Miduna..Your answer helped me to solve my first problem...Still i don't know how to disable html-body when pop-up is shown